# How to access validation border in Blazor to modify style?

Tags: validation, bootstrap-4, blazor

I have an input field and validating the form sets a green blazor border, however the form is using bootstrap class which gives it a round shape, and the border is squared.

I can apply styling only to bootstraps borders with a class
.valid or .invalid, but not the squared border, which comes from blazor.

TLDR: How to access squared blazor border ( for adding border-radius or removing it )

[image]

**Solved:**
Round border was outline, not the border, removing outline and adding border: 1px solid green, and modifying with border-radius solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

That is in the css file `app.css` inside the `wwwroot`. Or `site.css` in in earlier previews.

```
.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]) {
    outline: 1px solid #26b050;
}

.invalid {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I know how to apply styles to these classes, but these are responsible for the wrong border. 
These classes only apply styling not to the squared border, but to the round one, which is bootstraps border!
I need access to blazors squared border instead.

Comment: Ok i see, adding  outline shows me i can edit the squared border, but adding border-radius to the same class modifies the other border still, and then the squared remains

Comment: Can you update your question with the input element and applied classes?

Comment: So i removed the outline and added Border property and that belongs to the inside element, the outline was something entirely different which i was trying to modify with a border-radius.
Thnx!